# Can't get gdaltransform example work

Tags: gdal

When I am trying to run example of [gdaltransform](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html) I am getting error:

```
> gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:31370 177502 311865
ERROR 4: `177502' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

But it's copy-past example, and it should work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your copy-paste was losing the line feed. Hit enter after `gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:31370` and write `177502 311865` to the empty command line and then hit Enter again.

Comment: Cool! Thanks! How can I emulate it from programming language? I need to call this function and pass my coordinates there.

Comment: If you program, perhaps you would like to have a look at the source code https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdaltransform.cpp and adapt it for your needs.

Comment: alternatively, you can use cs2cs adding `<inputfile >outputfile`